# Setup URL redirection in SSRS without using IIS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We're using SSRS 2016 & SQL SERVER 2016 in our environment and don't want to use IIS. We've a requirement to re-direct report manager URL to Target URL (Similar to URL rewrite function of IIS).

For example:

http://ssrs01/pages/redirect.aspx?redirectnewurl

When someone access above URL they should be automatically routed to - "redirectnewurl"

I did research a lot and found this link useful which redirects from http: to https:

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26319133/SSRS-2008-R2-How-to-redirect-URL-from-http-to-https-when-IIS-not-installed.html

But we don't have any need to use SSL as it is only internal environment and looking for any other optimal solution by changing web.config file in my reporting server

Comment: following up on your question to see if you found a solution since its been so long.

Comment: We've made a workaround by setting up URL Redirection at network level but couldn't find any clean solution yet.

Comment: Thanks.. we used a solution of creating an internal and external dns record/hostname and do a port forwarding on the network firewall to basically route all calls from the external dns record to the internal dns record for ssrs. HTH somebody else. Our network infrastructure very different as its hosted and AD is not local as well as most of our servers sits behind a dmz.